# How can I check an "unexpected EOF" in my .tar.gz file?

Tags: tar, compression, gzip

Hi I have a problem with a .tar.gz file wich has backup of family photo collection and so.

I've tried [gzrecovery toolkit](http://www.urbanophile.com/arenn/coding/gzrt/gzrt.html) and i did

- `gzrecover file.tar.gz` and
- `cpio -F file.tar.recovered -i -v`

Buy i get the same: there is a partial decompression buy it says that it has an early EOF.

Is anything that I can do to know if my lost files are still there (and recover them) or I can yet cry?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a discussion about a similar problem. Hope it helps.
[Tar error: Unexpected EOF in archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325888/tar-error-unexpected-eof-in-archive)